# Text in munin graphs corrupted

Tags: munin, rrdtool

I'm having a problem in one of my servers, where munin is not able to write the text that accompanies each graph correctly. It is written as random squares, but I haven't found anything in the logs that could point me to the problem.

[image: munin corrupted graph]

Anyone had a similar problem? Thanks in advance, Simon.

**UPDATE**

I've found some lines in /var/mail/root regarding some problem with pango:

```
Pango-WARNING **: failed to choose a font, expect ugly output. engine-type='PangoRenderFc', script='latin'
```

Comment: This is typically due to the font being used not able to represent the glyph (character) that should be shown; however it's strange that everything becomes the box symbol. Maybe the font munin wants to use is not available at all.

Comment: FYI: on my munin server, `DejaVuSansMono.ttf` and `DejaVuSans.ttf` are used.

Comment: Thanks wurtel, but I have those fonts installed in my system. Just a question, where do you look for the font that munin uses?

Comment: I use Debian, and I checked the dependencies of munin and rrdtool (which contains rrdgraph that munin uses to draw the graphs). Then I checked the access times of the font files contained in the dependencies. They're also listed in `GraphOld.pm` which is the perl module that does the actual graphing.

Comment: Ty wurtel, same fonts here, and installed :/. Thx anyway!

Comment: Is the system locale set correctly (`/etc/locale-gen` on Archlinux, may be different on your distro) ? Try running `locale-gen` to regenerate locale files and see if that solves the issue (you may need to reboot).

Comment: This could be a problem with rrdtool. Did you try updating or reinstalling rrdtool?

Comment: Yes, everything is ok. Just in case, I ran locale-gen and rebooted without success. Thanks anyway André.

Comment: Yes Mehmet, I've tried to purge munin and the rrd packages without success :(.

Comment: The same problem with rrd graphs is mentioned [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=100416) with similar pictures, but you already covered the mono font possibility in previous comments, so not sure but might help.

Comment: Have you tried altering the fonts that munin/rrdtool are using to render the graphs - even taking into account that you do have the defaults installed locally?

Comment: I have the local fonts installed (ttf-dejavu, -core, -extras). I've thought about that but I don't really know where to change fonts. Any help will be appreciated ;).

Comment: If you run rrdtool by hand, do you have the same problem?

Comment: Also: When you installed rrdtool, did you do so from package or from source? This sort of thing _can_ occur with some of the (numerous) dependencies to RRDTool being broken.

Answer (score 1):

This could either be a problem with `rrd`, or a munin plugin.
Check the `munin-graph.log` and see if you have anything like this;

```
[RRD ERROR] Unable to graph <filename> : failed to load : failed to load $libdir/Some_Font_File.ttf
```

Another possibility is that munin is not able to *read* the font files in question (eg: the owner, group, or permissions are "wrong"), or there's a plugin interfering with the rendering.

Depending on the version of munin you're running, there should be a [munin-check](https://guide.munin-monitoring.org/en/latest/reference/munin-check.html) command that will fix various permissions (please read the man page before using, there's at least one caveat)

**EDIT:** This could also be an encoding problem. There's a [bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=598554) where munin assumes everything is going to be in ISO-8859-1. A [fix-request](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/munin/issues/839) was filed and munin 1.3 and higher should use `Encode::Guess` now ([details](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/munin/commit/cb67f8dc995de787742935f3c8f5f169ad181319)).

**EDIT #2:** Thanks to the additional comments, we now know two important things;

**1)** Software versions involved are

- Ubuntu 12 LTS
- munin: 1.4.6-3ubuntu3.4
- rrdtool: 1.4.7-1

**2)** There are multiple servers w/ this configuration, and only one is broken.

Therefore, there is probably a slight difference in the shell environment settings between two of the servers (the "broken" server versus a "known-good" server).

**Compare the Shell Environments on "broken" server & a "known-good" server**

**1)** Login to the user-account the graphs are being generated with

**2)** Run `env | sort > ~/shell_environment-User_Name-Server_Name.txt`

(Replace "`User_Name`" and "`Server_Name`" with the actual names involved.)

**3)** Copy both `shell_environment-*.txt` files to a single place and compare them.

There's probably a variable (maybe $LANG) that's different and breaking the rendering.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is nothing in the graph log related with fonts. 

I've passed munin-check and fixed some perms suggestions, but it stays the same. 

Thanks anyway for the effort Signal15.

Comment: @simon Could be an encoding problem (Added to the answer). What version of RRD & munin are you running?

Comment: They are the defaults packages in Ubuntu 12 LTS, munin: 1.4.6-3ubuntu3.4, rrdtool: 1.4.7-1...

The things is that I have other different servers with the same OS and the same munin installation and everything works. The problem is just with this one. 

Thx for trying!

Comment: @Simon In that case, I would find out what user-account the graphs are being generated with, `su -` to that user, then run `env | sort > ~/shell_environment.txt` on the Broken Server and a Working Server. There's probably a variable (maybe `$LANG`) that's different and breaking the rendering.

Comment: No luck. Both envs have the same lang defined (LANG=es_ES.UTF-8). These are the differences: http://pastebin.com/jnsaFzbk. The only thing noticeable is that the env command in the server with the bad munin, env wasn't in the path of my regular user (I need to run it from its absolute path /usr/bin/env).

Comment: just for giggles, change it to `en_US.UTF-8` or just `en_ES` and see if that clears it up.

Comment: done with reboot, no luck :(

Comment: I've just found some log lines in /var/mail/root with pango and fonts problems: Pango-WARNING **: failed to choose a font, expect ugly output. engine-type='PangoRenderFc', script='latin'. I'm gonna investigate it...

Comment: @simon if you find the root-cause to the problem , feel free to post an "Answer" and mark it as accepted. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

On alpine I ran `apk add ttf-opensans` and `su-exec munin:root munin-cron`

You can see that it is starting to work as graphs refresh

[image: Graphs]